# Caching cakephp views with key

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

I need a small help. I'm using `cakephp's default cache engine (File)` and want to save the `view caches by key`. This is beacause my site is multilangual and I use `session` to save the language instead of the `url prefix`. 
Is it possible to add a `prefix or suffix` in the cache file for controller ?
I'm using `cakephp 5.2` in `apache server`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either you are a time traveler, or you are actually using CakePHP **2**.5.2, or maybe PHP 5.2 and CakePHP ?.?.?

Comment: Semantics are important, don't use ``code tags`` for *emphasis* it's like **CAPITALIZING** for no reason.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are going to clarify the details, so let me just add this link, from there you can figure it out by yourself: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html#using-the-helper**

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [groups-cache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#using-groups) as far as prefix goes :

```
Cache::config(
    $this->cacheConfig, 
    array(
        'engine' => 'File', 
        'duration' => TIME, 
        'prefix' => KEY,    
        'groups' => array(
            'GROUP_A'
        )
   )
);
```